# Register string value for concrete name of parameter

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I am using Autofac and I have several classes which ask for parameter of type string and name lang. Is there a way to register a string value to all parameters named "lang", so it resolves automatically? I do not want to edit any of the constructors, since it is not my code (I know accepting e.g. CultureInfo would make registration easy..)

Something resulting in short syntax like
 builder.Register(lang => "en-US").As().Named("lang")

would be ideal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A fairly simple way to solve this is with a custom Autofac module.

First, implement the module and handle the IComponentRegistration.Preparing event. This is also where you'll store the value for your parameter:

```
using System;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;

public class LangModule : Module:
{
  private string _lang;
  public LangModule(string lang)
  {
    this._lang = lang;
  }

  protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
    IComponentRegistry componentRegistry,
    IComponentRegistration registration)
  {
    // Any time a component is resolved, it goes through Preparing
    registration.Preparing += InjectLangParameter;
  }

  protected void InjectLangParameter(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
  {
    // Add your named parameter to the list of available parameters.
    e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
      new[] { new NamedParameter("lang", this._lang) });
  }
}
```

Now that you have your custom module, you can register it along with your other dependencies and provide the value you want injected.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new LangModule("my-language"));
builder.RegisterType<LangConsumer>();
...
var container = builder.Build();
```

Now when you resolve any type that has a string parameter "lang" your module will insert the value you provided.

If you need to be more specific, you can use the PreparingEventArgs in the event handler to determine things like which type is being resolved (`e.Component.Activator.LimitType`), etc. Then you can decide on the fly whether to include your parameter.

Comment: Haven´t tried it yet, but looks exactly like what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Travis - can this be adapted to work with property injection, too?

Comment: I'm sure it probably could, but I'm going to leave that as "an exercise for the reader."

Comment: @TravisIllig hi Travis, Can we do something similar with RegisterAssemblyModules too where we can pass some property/constructor information like a string value to the Module

Comment: No, because which module would the constructor parameter go to? Let's say you have 100 modules coming in and 30 of them take a string parameter and that parameter has a different meaning for each. How would you provide that? So, no, you can't provide parameters when you're scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

```
builder.Register<ClassName>((c, p) =>
{
var p2 = p.Named<string>("lang");
return new ClassName(p2);
});
var container = builder.Build();
var m = container.Resolve<ClassName>(new NamedParameter("lang", "en-US"));
var m2 = container.Resolve<ClassName>(new NamedParameter("lang", "fr-FR"));
```

you can resolve your class and pass parameters in constructor.

Comment: This works, however one needs to do this Resolve for each of the classes automatically, which is the same as the current scenarion only with different syntax.

Comment: I am looking for something which would resolve this parameter for all classes automatically (or all classes of a given assembly)

Comment: Well, when you call Register you can pass a factory method in it. You can pass there something like `() => { return new ClassName(GetLangString()); }`

Comment: But it still requires to call this for all of the classes with "string lang" in constructor. I am loking for a solution of O(1) LinesOfCode, not O(Number of involved classes) LOC.

Comment: Do you have lot's of classes with `lang` parameters in constructors?  Ok, I see that my variant is not sutable.

Comment: I've checked Builder unit tests, and I think that you can't do that with Autofac. [UnitTest](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Test/Autofac.Tests/ContainerBuilderTests.cs)